# How to get KNIME workflow name within a workflow

Tags: knime

Which node do I need to get a KNIME workflow name within the workflow?  I am using KNIME version 2.11, and would like to add this information to the table being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who came across this in Google search, you can use **"Extract Context Properties"** under IO>Other categories.  This will give you the flow variable port, which will contain the workflow name.

I've used **"Variable to Table Column"** then **"Unpivoting"** nodes to turn it into a table.